# Mysql Query taking time

Tags: optimization, mysql, subquery

Qe : 1)

```
select 
  a.finishproductid 
from 
  tblt_invoiceorderitems a, tblm_invoiceorder b 
where 
  b.invoiceorderdate <= 'Current Date' and 
  a.invoiceorderid = b.invoiceorderid
```

--- it has more than 16k records.

Qe : 2 )

```
select jobcardid, stockcode 
from tblm_finishproduct 
where productionentrydate <= 'Current Date'
```

--- it has also more than 16k Record.

Now i Want From 2nd Query not in  first query.

```
select jobcardid, stockcode 
from 
  tblm_finishproduct 
where 
  productionentrydate <= 'CurrrntDate' and 
  finishproductid not in 
  (
    select 
      a.finishproductid 
    from 
      tblt_invoiceorderitems a, tblm_invoiceorder b 
    where 
      b.invoiceorderdate <= 'CurrrntDate' and 
      a.invoiceorderid = b.invoiceorderid
  );
```

Now its taking a time

Comment: Please use code blocks for the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not address your question, but you should not be using `a.invoiceorderid = b.invoiceorderid` in your where clause--try this query in place of the first one.  [Natural join](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join) is more efficient than making a cross product of the entire table and selecting only those rows that match.

```
select a.finishproductid 
from tblt_invoiceorderitems a 
natural join tblm_invoiceorder b 
where b.invoiceorderdate <= 'Current Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the not in:

```
b.invoiceorderdate <= 'CurrrntDate' and
```

Answer (score 0):

the result of "select Table1, Table2, Table3" maby is 16k^3 or 16k^2. You need make a "inner join" or "join" using primary key to cout the search.

See u.